# Dynamic merge on multi-dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I have some multi dimensional array that needs to be merged while preserving some of it's values.

```
Array
(
    [diagnosa_id] => 6
    [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
    [diagnosa] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [diagnosa_kode] => A01.0
                [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
                [pasienhidupmati] => HIDUP
                [diagnosa_nama] => Demam tifoid
                [jmlpasien] => 1
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [diagnosa_kode] => A01.0
                [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
                [pasienhidupmati] => HIDUP
                [diagnosa_nama] => Demam tifoid
                [jmlpasien] => 1
            )

    )

)

Array
(
    [diagnosa_id] => 1
    [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
    [diagnosa] => Array
    (
        [1] => Array
            (
                [diagnosa_kode] => A00
                [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
                [pasienhidupmati] => HIDUP
                [diagnosa_nama] => Kolera
                [jmlpasien] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [diagnosa_kode] => A00
                [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
                [pasienhidupmati] => HIDUP
                [diagnosa_nama] => Kolera
                [jmlpasien] => 1
            )

    )

)

Array
(
    [diagnosa_id] => 7
    [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
    [diagnosa] => Array
    (
        [3] => Array
            (
                [diagnosa_kode] => A01.1
                [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
                [pasienhidupmati] => HIDUP
                [diagnosa_nama] => Demam paratifoid A
                [jmlpasien] => 1
            )

    )

)
```

As you can see, the first two array have a similar data on `[diagnosa]` array. I need to combine the array inside the `[diagnosa]` array.

So if the array inside it have same value on it's `[diagnosa_kode], [jeniskelamin], [pasienhidupmati],` and `[diagnosa_nama]`, then it should add the `[jmlpasien]` value, while preserving the other value.

For example, on the first array, the result should be like this:

```
Array
(
    [diagnosa_id] => 6
    [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
    [diagnosa] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [diagnosa_kode] => A01.0
                [jeniskelamin] => LAKI-LAKI
                [pasienhidupmati] => HIDUP
                [diagnosa_nama] => Demam tifoid
                [jmlpasien] => 2
            )       

    )

)
```

Sorry if it's too complicated, but I just can't figure it out on implementing it on php.

Comment: in your first example array, is this inside another parent array that holds them all? or are these separate arrays?

Comment: The [diagnosa] array is inside it's parent arrray along with [diagnosa_id] and [jeniskelamin]. And yes, they're inside another parent array that hold them all.

Comment: okay I answered bellow, also added a fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it, you just need a temporary holder for the grouping, and then after merging you can put them back again. Example:

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $diagnosa = $value['diagnosa'];
    $temp = array(); // initialize the temp holder
    foreach($diagnosa as $d) {
        $name = "$d[diagnosa_kode] - $d[jeniskelamin] - $d[pasienhidupmati]"; // create a grouping index
        if(!isset($temp[$name])) {
            $temp[$name] = $d; // simple group initialization
        } else {
            $temp[$name]['jmlpasien'] += $d['jmlpasien']; // if its there already, just added them up
        }
    }
    $diagnosa = array_values($temp); // simple reindexing
    $value['diagnosa'] = $diagnosa; // overwrite the values
}
```

[Fiddle](http://codepad.viper-7.com/MoUZVl)

Answer (score 0):

if you merge both arrays try this:

```
$final_array =array();
foreach ($data as $val)
{
foreach($val as $val2)
 {
    $final_array[] = $val2;
 }
}
```